# Why do I get an OutOfMemoryException from XmlTextReaderImpl.InitStreamInput when using XmlReader?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, out-of-memory

When I try to read an xml file, and create objects from the data within,
I am inconsistently (2 out of ~100 xml reads) receiving the following error:

```
System. OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System. OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InitStreaminput(Uri baseUri. String baseUriStr, Stream stream, Byte/ bytes, Int32 byteCount, Encoding encoding) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishinitUriString
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSetting settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputuri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputuri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri)
```

I am not sure that the size of the file is important because it would appear that the error is occurring before the file is read, and because I have read larger files without issue. The file that was being read at the time was 186KB and for reference we deal with files that are larger (~0.5MB) and smaller.

The system has a lot more memory than this process should require (8GB).
My only theory that I have is that the AV or some other process happened to be using insane amounts of memory at exactly the time of the failures.

But I am naïve about how the XmlTextReader consumes memory, so maybe there is some logical explanation.

This is the code I am using to read and parse the xml into objects.

```
    // Create the list of xml models to be generated
    var xmlModels = new List<Xml_Model>();

    // Read the xml file.
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath))
    {
        var endCreate = false;
        var xmlModel = new Xml_Model();
        var isStartDate = false;
        var dateString = string.Empty;
        var entityResult = new Result_Model();
        var dataType = string.Empty;

        // Read each node in turn.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Get the dataType.
            if (reader.Name != string.Empty) dataType = reader.Name;

            // If the value is empty, this is a starting or closing element and we should continue, unless its a special case.
            if (reader.Value == string.Empty || reader.Value.Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                if (!(reader.Name == "gate_results" || reader.Name == "entity_results"
                                                  || reader.Name == "stop_date"
                                                  || reader.Name == "start_date"))
                    continue;
            }
            
            // Depending on the node type, carry out an operation.
            switch (dataType)
            {
                case "gate_results":
                    // Add the created object to the list, or begin creating a new object.
                    if (endCreate)
                    {
                        endCreate = false;
                        xmlModels.Add(xmlModel);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        endCreate = true;
                        xmlModel = new Xml_Model();
                    }
                    break;
                case "gate_no": xmlModel.GateNo = reader.Value; break;
                case "operator": xmlModel.TestOperator = reader.Value; break;
                case "test_status": xmlModel.TestStatus = reader.Value; break;
                case "serial_no": xmlModel.SerialNo = reader.Value; break;
                case "f_serial_no": xmlModel.FSerialNo = reader.Value; break;
                case "product_type": xmlModel.ProductType = reader.Value; break;
                case "part_no": xmlModel.PartNo = reader.Value; break;
                case "test_procedure": xmlModel.TestProcedure = reader.Value; break;
                case "start_date": isStartDate = true; break;
                case "stop_date": isStartDate = false; break;
                case "year": dateString += reader.Value; break;
                case "month": dateString += reader.Value; break;
                case "day": dateString += reader.Value; break;
                case "hour": dateString += reader.Value; break;
                case "minute": dateString += reader.Value; break;
                case "second":
                    dateString += reader.Value;
                    if (isStartDate)
                    {
                        xmlModel.StartDate = dateString;
                        dateString = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xmlModel.StopDate = dateString;
                        dateString = string.Empty;
                    }
                    break;
                case "result": xmlModel.Result = reader.Value; break;
                case "failure_mode": xmlModel.FailureMode = reader.Value; break;
                case "entity_results":
                    // Add a completed entity result to the list and create a new entity result.
                    if (entityResult.ResultId != 0)
                    {
                        xmlModel.EntityResults.Add(entityResult);
                        entityResult = new Result_Model();
                    }
                    break;
                case "result_id": entityResult.ResultId = int.Parse(reader.Value); break;
                case "key": entityResult.Key = reader.Value; break;
                case "result_desc": entityResult.ResultDesc = reader.Value; break;
                case "entity_no": entityResult.Entity = reader.Value; break;
                case "line_no": entityResult.LineNo = int.Parse(reader.Value); break;
                case "measure_no": entityResult.MeasureNo = int.Parse(reader.Value); break;
                case "measurement": entityResult.Measurement = reader.Value; break;
                case "low_limit": entityResult.LowLimit = reader.Value; break;
                case "high_limit": entityResult.UpperLimit = reader.Value; break;
                case "debug": entityResult.Debug = reader.Value; break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have copied this code into a sandbox project and ran the function on the xml files that previously failed with this error and could not repeat the error, and the total memory usage for the sandbox project just inside the using directive was 9.2MB and by the end of creating the object the usage was 12.3MB.

Comment: Perhaps it's the way you are dealing with your strings. Here is Microsoft's document on Out Of Memory exceptions and string building: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-outofmemoryexception#string-concatenation

Comment: Interesting idea, I don't think that would be the case in this particular function, but I am willing to investigate if this being done elsewhere is causing lots of memory to be eaten up. I'll do a deeper dive into the memory usage from other parts of the application.

Comment: There are other things mentioned on that page I linked worth looking into. It's hard to say, considering you're saying this works in a sandboxed environment. Perhaps it's not even the code, like you had mentioned.